# Set notation for all real numbers

Tags: functions

Consider a function,

$$
y=f(x)=2x-\tan x,
$$

where the domain of the function is the interval $\left(-\dfrac{\pi}{2},\dfrac{\pi}{2}\right)$.

I know the range is the set of all real numbers. Thus I state that,

"The range of the function is,

$$
\{y~|~y\in{\rm I\!R}\}.
$$

"

I wish to use set notation to convey this. Keeping this in mind, is there any way my statement can be improved? Regarding the notation, is it correctly used?

Comment: Why don't you say "the range of $f$ is $\mathbb R$"?

Comment: @PaulFrost Trying to stick to the set notation.

Comment: It’s fine, but $\mathbb R$ is just simpler, as it is a set itself and $\mathbb R=\{y|y\in\mathbb R\}$.

Comment: @insipidintegrator I realize it is simpler, but for a reason (too long a story and unnecessary), I am stuck using set notations. 

Thank you for confirming that it is fine. Appreciate it. I looked up the syntax for set notation but all the examples came with conditions. Wanted to confirm this was correct.